# Javascript element children about function parameter

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes, element

Below is part of a code that makes a sideshow. What confused me is:
In this case, what is the parameter "container"'s equivalent DOM node?
There are bunch of elements, how does it consider `<img>` elements are container.children?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/birds_rainbow-lorakeets.png" alt="Rainbow lorakeets" />
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/butterfly.png"alt="Butterfly" />
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/cat.png" alt="Cat" />
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/crocodiles.png" alt="Crocodiles" />
        <img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/fox.png" alt="Fox" />

    </div>

    <script>
var slideShow = function(container) {
    this.images = [];
    this.curImage = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < container.childElementCount; i++) {
        this.images.push(container.children[i]);
        this.images[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Elements that are directly nested in another element in the DOM hierarchy are its children.

Comment: So `<head>` and `<body>` are children of `<html>`, `<div>` and `<script>` are children of `<body>`, and the images are children of `<div id="slideshow">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`container` is whatever element you pass when you call `new slideShow()`. In your case, it should be:

```
var ss = new slideShow(document.getElementById('slideshow'));
```

Then `container.children` is the elements that are directly nested in that DIV, which are all the `<img>` elements.

Comment: Yeah, I'm totally a dumb. The last line of the script code is `slideShow(document.getElementById("slideshow"));` No wonder I'm so confused... Thx